# Current environment doesn't support interactive reading from TTY?? Azure pipeline, Anypoint

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, anypoint-studio

I am trying to build a pipeline which would install anypoint studio in AzureDevops. I have added the Command line plugin for executing cli commands. However after installing anypoint studio using cli, I am getting the error as seen in the image.

The Pipeline is as follows:

```
npm cache clean -f
npm install -g n
sudo n stable
npm install -g anypoint-cli@latest
anypoint-cli --username="XXXX"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this meant the installer prompts you to input some information, but you obviously cant during the pipeline execution.

You need to figure out the proper command to silently install it.

Comment: But it looks like it is being installed successfully, it's just that it's not taking credentials.

Comment: well, it doesnt really matter. what matters - it prompts something, and that will not work, you need to fix that

Comment: Right, but how do I go about in fixing that?

Comment: I have no idea, i never saw this anypoint studio. check their documentation. they should have means of silent install (hopefully)